# Installing third party APK from another App

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

Currently I'm developing an app and I included an `apk` that created by third party to be installed on specific condition. This `apk` is stored on `assets` folder. The problem is when I tried to install the third party apk, it ask me to activate allow the unknown source setting.

My questions are,

1. Can an `.apk` file contain another third party `.apk` file in its assets directory while uploading to Google Play?
2. Is it possible to sign a third party apk (make it known source)? So it won't prompt the user to allow the setting.

Comment: Yes, you can sign with valid certificate the third party .apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Can `.apk` file contain another third party `.apk` file in its assets directory while uploading to Google Play?

**Yes**, I am sure that we can.

> 2. Is it possible to sign that third party `.apk` (make it known source)? So it won't prompt the user to allow the setting

It is not something about the app signature, but the source of app installation. The only trusted source is the `Google Play`. All other sources (including assets directory of other APK regardless of where it has been installed from) are not trusted sources. If you want to avoid that problem - prompt to install the 3rd-party app from Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, we cannot install `.apk` without user's explicit permission unless the device is rooted.

Due to the security reasons, Google has forbidden that behaviour

Comment: how about my first question? is it possible to submit an apk that contain another apk in it?

Answer (score 0):

Let me warn you that this is an absolutely terrible idea. This is precisely the sort of thing which will get your app to be very likely suspected as malware, and you are far more likely to get your app and developer account banned as a result. There is no good reason for a legitimate app to do this, and lots of reasons for a malware app to do this.

It also puts you at huge risk to the third party. If that app does anything bad that breaks the Play store policies then your app will be held responsible as it is included.

If you aren't producing malware, I'd be very curious why you want to do this.